# Select within a select from separate tables using results from inner select

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL. I have two tables which share a few ids (product_id in first table is the same id as post_id in second table).

[image: First table: wp_wcmp_products_map]

[image: Second table: wp_postmeta]

I need to find the rows from meta_value column from the second table (wp_postmeta) with the same product_id (like post_id=49) where meta_key='_product_attributes'.

Comment: @timbiegeleisen So do I.

Comment: Your current query is _already_ a single statement.  What is wrong with it?

Comment: Please read the question. I don't think you get what I'm trying to achieve. Don't downvote too soon @Strawberry

Comment: Ok. Let me no when it's not too soon,  and I'll stick my dv in then.

Comment: I'm letting you know now @Strawberry

Comment: @warnerque, you *do* have a good sense of humour! For that alone your question deserves my upvote! ;-)

Comment: Ok - I'm downvoting now then

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same table with different alias and a INNER JOIN  and then join the wp_postmeta

```
SELECT a.*, c.*
FROM wp_wcmp_products_map a
INNER JOIN wp_wcmp_products_map b ON a.product_map_id = b.product_map_id 
  AND b.product_id = 3479  
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta c on c.post_id = b.product_id 
  AND c.meta_key = '_product_attributes'
```

Comment: Thx but this is not what I meant. I need to derive a select statement from the statement I posted.

Comment: answer updated .  .. ( anyway a valid  data sample and the expected  result  ..help a lot  ..  )

Comment: I'm trying to be as fast as fellow @Strawberry here by marking this as the answer. I guess, my upvote is more useful to all than his downvote

Comment: @warnerque  upvote .. downvote are part of the game ..  just a suggestion  .. instead of img (or only img)  you should poste the question with valid data sample as  tabular text  and  .. a clear expected  result  .. (in you img .. is not so clear)

Comment: Sorry @scaisEdge but it doesn't show the desired result but close. (Result here: https://imgur.com/a/WO76hoV) Each post_id (or product_id) has its own '_product_attributes'. But from the result I got, I only received the meta_value for one product_id (3479). Not those from the other product_ids.

Comment: your comment is not clear  ..but you can work on the condtion  in ON clause  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta c on c.post_id = b.product_id   for choose the value returned  form wp_metapost ..  In my answer  i return the values for c.post_id = b.product_id   asi in your original question ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193614/discussion-between-warnerque-and-scaisedge).

Comment: Great! I found the answer using subquery. Thanks anyway.